# interactive shell script for execution of sudo commands

Tags: macos, bash, makefile, sh, sudo

I installed gcc 5.2 with gmp, mpfr and mpc, plus the isl and cloog optimizations, works perfectly. All prefixes are in `/usr/local` so that I have to `sudo`my `make install`'s. I had to redo the same install on the computer of a friend, and now, I have to do it on another computer of mine... It's enough, so that I wrote a script. (And broke my "script whatever you have to do twice" rule.) My problem is that at some places of the script I have `sudo make install` commands, and that I don't want to run my script as admin.

How could I modify my script so that the following happens : before each `sudo make install` command one is asked to elevate permissions, and if one accepts, one is asked the root password, and then, `sudo make install` is executed, and after, the next commands are executed with "normal" permissions, until the next `sudo make install`, etc... ?

(I tagged make but the question is of course independant of it.)

Comment: I probably haven't understood your question correctly, but what's wrong with having a script that does the equivalent of `configure && make && sudo make install`?

Comment: yes, or something with sub-shells, that eliminate any environment changes once they have closed. Something like `configure && make && (sudo make install)` ... Just an idea. Good luck.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't ask you for the root password, but your own; and it only does this when you haven't `sudo`ed recently enough. So just put `sudo :` at the top of the script, so it will ask for the password right away, and all the other `sudo` commands will execute without asking anything.

Comment: @reinierpost This is the answer I was looking for, thx !

Comment: @reinierpost: Can you make your comment as an answer? I`m sure it will be helpful for futher readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash scripts requiring sudo password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976362/bash-scripts-requiring-sudo-password)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` doesn't ask you for the root password, but your own; and it only does this when you haven't sudoed recently enough.

So just put `sudo :` at the top of the script: then it will ask for the password right away, and after it has been supplied, all the other `sudo` commands will execute without asking anything.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this work for all bash scripts or ? How to be sure to exit from super user rights at the end of the script ?

Comment: `sudo <command>` executes that one command with super user rights. So every line without `sudo` runs without those rights. That is why working with `sudo` beats working in a root shell.